# After new version of jsViews, depends not working

Tags: jsviews

I updated last version of jsView in my application, after that depends does not working.

myFuction.depends = [entity,"PropertyObject.**"]

Before update to last version it worked.

Someone knew what had changed?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me. Can you provide a simple repro sample, which worked on the previous version and fails after the update?

Even better, report a new issue here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues, and include a repro sample there

---

.

Comment: The problem solved. I just forgot to update one of the files.
Thank

Comment: OK - maybe you could actually remove your question, to reduce confusion.